# Custom ribbon Excel XML

Tags: xml, excel, ribbon

I would like to create a custom item in MS Excel using XML. Within this item there will be several groups and within each groups a number of buttoms to callback vba macros.

I am able to set up a single group many button XML (Code 1), but I am unable to set up several groups with a number of buttons (Code 2).

I am not familiar with XML, so I would appreciate your insights where I am going wrong.

Code 1

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="AA PAYMENTS APP" insertAfterMso="TabView">
                <group id="customGroup" label="Group 1">
                    <button id="customButton" label="Test1" imageMso="HyperlinkInsert" size="large" onAction="Callback" />
                    <button id="customButton2" label="JG Button 2" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback2" />
                    <button id="customButton3" label="Validate and Submit" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback3" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Code 2

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="AA PAYMENTS APP" insertAfterMso="TabView">
                <group id="customGroup" label="Group 1">
                    <button id="customButton" label="Test1" imageMso="HyperlinkInsert" size="large" onAction="Callback" />
                    <button id="customButton2" label="JG Button 2" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback2" />
                <group id="customGroup2" label="Group 2">
                    <button id="customButton3" label="Validate and Submit" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback3" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

N.B I use Custom UI Editor.

Comment: You have to close a group `</group>` before starting a new group `<group>`. I suppose you might be able to nest them (I've never tried) but you didn't close the nest properly. Every `<group>` needs to be closed with a `</group>`.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. You can add that to answers and I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close a group with `</group>` before starting a new group with `<group>`. I suppose you might be able to nest them (I've never tried) but you didn't close the nest properly. Every `<group>` needs to be closed with a `</group>`.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="AA PAYMENTS APP" insertAfterMso="TabView">
                <group id="customGroup" label="Group 1">
                    <button id="customButton" label="Test1" imageMso="HyperlinkInsert" size="large" onAction="Callback" />
                    <button id="customButton2" label="JG Button 2" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback2" />
                </group>
                <group id="customGroup2" label="Group 2">
                    <button id="customButton3" label="Validate and Submit" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback3" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```